# Serverside Cache: Should this be used for a high traffic but small-sized DB?

Tags: caching, redis, memcached

I have an application which will read from a DB (very infrequent write operations - expecting a few dozen requests per day at max. However expecting a large amount of read operations (100k or more). 
The database size is small (< 100 records in total).

Should I expect such a system to function responsively simply by reading from a DB directly (given small number of records and supposedly short retrieval times)? Or should I still look at implementing a caching solution (e.g. Redis or Memcached) and retrieve the records from memory?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience caching a small table (<100 records) is not worth the effort and added complication. Modern SQL servers (I've used MsSql, Oracle and Postgres) are very good at caching in your scenario and they appear to keep those frequently requested query results in memory already.

That said, if the SQL server is performing other queries which are heavier it could have an effect on your small query, in which case caching might be more appropriate.

SQL Profiling the production server can help too.